# How to setup a loader - Android

Tags: android, loader

I am doing the udacity Android Development course. They show how to setup a loader in MainActivity.java like this :

```
LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
loaderManager.initLoader(EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

For me, when I type LoaderManager, the autosuggestion shows me "LoaderManager" with a line in center saying LoaderManager is deprecated. Even when I type the whole code, I get this error :

```
Required androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager
Found android.app.LoaderManager
```

How can I make this work

Comment: Make sure that all of your Loader-related imports are coming from `androidx.loader.app`, and use `getSupportLoaderManager()` instead of `getLoaderManager()`. Loaders are deprecated in general, though, so I'm not sure if you can get that warning to go away entirely.

Comment: Mike, so what is the best alternative to loaders in the current version?

Comment: They're deprecated in favor of `ViewModel`/`LiveData` setups. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.

Comment: I was trying to use loader to make a network connection on the background thread. Do you think they are useful for that purpose?